# Is there any way to customize progress bar in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, progress-bar

I'm looking a way to do this progress bar step, let's say for a registration process.

[image: custom progrees bar]

I tried putting 4 Images and 3 Labels in a row like this

```
    <Page loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <ActionBar title="Register"></ActionBar>

    <AbsoluteLayout class="home-panel" width="500" height="65"
        borderColor="black" borderWidth="1">
        <Image width="50" height="50"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTjuRgmqRR4U-fUyGU1Xf-Y1IEnInqqVtxm9w&usqp=CAU"
            left="10" top="5">
        </Image>
        <Image width="50" height="50"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTjuRgmqRR4U-fUyGU1Xf-Y1IEnInqqVtxm9w&usqp=CAU"
            left="100" top="5">
        </Image>
        <Image width="50" height="50"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTjuRgmqRR4U-fUyGU1Xf-Y1IEnInqqVtxm9w&usqp=CAU"
            left="200" top="5">
        </Image>
        <Image width="50" height="50"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTjuRgmqRR4U-fUyGU1Xf-Y1IEnInqqVtxm9w&usqp=CAU"
            left="300" top="5">
        </Image>

        <Label
            style="background-color: green; height: 20; width: 60; border-radius: 50%;"
            left="50" top="20"></Label>

        <Label
            style="background-color: green; height: 20; width: 70; border-radius: 50%;"
            left="140" top="20"></Label>

        <Label
            style="background-color: green; height: 20; width: 70; border-radius: 50%;"
            left="240" top="20"></Label>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</Page>
```

But I'm not a really fan, firstly because using AbsoluteLayout makes it difficult to adapt it on different screens (what if it is a tablet ?)

And secondly it seems to me as ugly workaround, i've been struggling a lot with shapes in nativescript, guess that it is not really friendly.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this ?

[Playground Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=iukxKJ)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using NativeScript core, but the logic is the same.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/progress

In the docs it shows that the progress bar has a property called called **value** in which you can put how much is the progress bar set to.

You can control the progress bar with code behind or on the view and hard code it on every page you need.

Example :

```
<!-- scaleY makes the bar thicker -->
<Progress value="25" maxValue="100" scaleY="15" />
```

Comment: well actually when you do that it scale the whole progress bar. I don't think there is another way to achieve this unless by going through custom components....